# Convert a varchar(16) from sql, into a functional time using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, casting

EDITED to reflect some changes recommended below.

I am pulling some times and minutes down from my database. They look like this in the db

```
| taskID |    startTime     |      endTime     |   everyMinutes   |
|________|__________________|__________________|__________________|
|   10   | 05:00:00.0000000 | 16:59:00.0000000 | 00:15:00.0000000 |
```

`startTime`, `endTime`, and `everyMinutes` are of `varchar(16)`. Unfortunately I can't change this.

I have those values in variables with:

```
$strStartTime = $row['startTime'];
$strEndTime = $row['endTime'];
$strEveryMinutes = $row['everyMinutes'];

$startTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($strStartTime));
$endTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($strEndTime));
$everyMinutes = date('H:i:s', strtotime($strEveryMinutes));

$composite = $startTime + $everyMinutes;
echo $composite; # returns "5", should be "5:15"
```

My goal is to take `$startTime` and add it to `$everyMinutes` so that if you

```
 echo $composite # displays "05:15:00" without all the extra 0's
```

Comment: If you would love to work from database side `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42988/48` and i have gave brief function of conversion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('05:00:00.000000'))."<br/>\n";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('05:00:00.000000 + 15 minutes'))."<br/>\n";
?>
```

output:

```
2013-04-16 05:00:00
2013-04-16 05:15:00
```

**edit**: the full code:

```
$startTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['startTime']));
$minutes = substr($row['everyMinutes'], 3, 2); // this will cut out the minutes part. I am assuming everyMinutes is always only in minutes.
$composite = date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['startTime']." + $minutes minutes"));
```

Comment: I have edited the above code. Using `strtotime` and `date` however it still isn't returning the valid answer

Comment: strtotime is powerful, but as you see it will create a time of today + the hours and minutes given. So when you add them you will get the time since 1-1-1970 added to today. That's why you have to use substr() to get the amount of minutes to add out of $everyMinutes.